# Rest Assured Database Check Against Returned values from response

Tags: rest, integration-testing, rest-assured

Suppose in Integration Test, I need to check the values returned in my Test against the result that is stored in DB. I am using Rest-Assured for Integration Testing. So any help on how to do it?
Reference :-

[Integration Testing automation - checking DB values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932459/integration-testing-automation-checking-db-values)

Comment: Do you have problems with extracting data from DB? There is no difference between checking response vs any data source.

Comment: Suppose a Post request to http://localhost:8080/gethelp/response gives me a json response.Now I need to check this response against the data what I have in Db.Used Dbunit but getting xml file.So any other better option.

Comment: In our project we are using a simple DbClient over JDBC. But as for me using DB check in integration tests is the last option, we are avoiding it when ever is possible. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950002/is-there-a-dbunit-like-framework-that-doesnt-suck-for-java-scala) and this [link](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-database.html)  probably they would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest-Assured don't allow to check data in DB ( at least not directly ). It's just for api response testing and if you want to check if data has been well store in DB you have to use basic testing method of your used language or technogy, and just check data after fetching them.

Of course you will need to have a good db configuration for your integration test ( as example [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/) can be a good way for that ). Hope this could be helpful.